# Does a switch protect network

Tags: network

I got a mesh router downstairs. Aoes a switch protect your network if connected to the mesh router?

Comment: A dumb switch does not provide any kind of meaningful protection.

Comment: "protect your network" *from what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the capabilities of the switch, Arisa for example have ACL support and some firewall capabilities on it, so depends on the product basically.

Answer (score 1):

Switch just connects network parts. It is not a firewall. If you mean "can switch provide protection like firewall", then the answer is NO.